# Process ID max limit and what happens after

Tags: mysql-8.0

Process ID is bigint in information schema.
What happens when limit is reached?
Do I need to restart MySQL to 0 it out again?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se!  If you have a billion processes per second for 300 years, you still won't max out an unsigned bigint. You'll probably have retired by then! :-)

Comment: @Vérace i should have done the math before asking! thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) says:

> When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails.

Found this: [What to do if the auto-increment value reaches its limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365450/what-to-do-if-the-auto-increment-value-reaches-its-limit)

So either update the table column for a larger type, or handle the error and the consequences of having the reset of the key values.